# How can I use the result of a formula in another cell and pull the data 1 cell to the right of the original search data

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am using Max(Index to find the data in a table with the search query being the date. i also need the data 1 cell to the right of the date column.

I have tried Offset(Max(Index but that just yielded a reference error. i have tried searching online but have found no other way of doing this. What i expected to happen was the data 1 cell to the right of the search query was found and pulled to the spreadsheet.
below is the formula used that did not work

`=OFFSET(MAX(INDEX((D16='Sheet1'!B$2:B$7500)*'Sheet1'!C$2:C$7500,)),0,1)`

attached is some sample data from sheet 1

| search query | date | cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100336288 | 11 July 2023 | -£200.00 |
| 100025143 | 11 July 2023 | -£50.00 |
| 100301369 | 11 July 2023 | -£5,771.40 |
| 100280645 | 11 July 2023 | -£500.00 |
| 100138224 | 11 July 2023 | -£50.00 |
| 100336288 | 30 June 2023 | -£3,000.00 |
| 100336288 | 26 June 2023 | -£999.51 |
| 100280645 | 20 June 2023 | -£167.36 |
| 100280645 | 20 June 2023 | -£332.64 |
| 100025143 | 14 June 2023 | -£50.00 |
| 100138224 | 12 June 2023 | -£50.00 |
| 100336288 | 07 June 2023 | -£200.00 |
| 100336288 | 06 June 2023 | -£700.00 |
| 100336288 | 02 June 2023 | -£1,500.00 |
| 100301369 | 02 June 2023 | -£3,000.00 |
| 100138224 | 12 May 2023 | -£50.00 |
| 100336288 | 09 May 2023 | -£200.00 |
| 100025143 | 08 May 2023 | -£50.00 |
| 100336288 | 04 May 2023 | -£700.00 |
| 100336288 | 13 April 2023 | -£200.00 |
| 100025143 | 12 April 2023 | -£50.00 |
| 100336288 | 04 April 2023 | -£700.00 |
| 100336288 | 13 March 2023 | -£804.44 |
| 100025143 | 11 March 2023 | -£50.00 |
| 100336288 | 07 March 2023 | -£700.00 |
| 100336288 | 06 March 2023 | -£200.00 |
| 100025143 | 10 February 2023 | -£50.00 |
| 100336288 | 06 February 2023 | -£200.00 |
| 100336288 | 06 February 2023 | -£982.00 |
| 100336288 | 06 February 2023 | -£700.00 |
| 100025143 | 17 January 2023 | -£50.00 |
| 100336288 | 09 January 2023 | -£200.00 |
| 100025143 | 06 January 2023 | -£50.00 |
| 100336288 | 05 January 2023 | -£982.00 |

sheet 2 sample data
i have removed the = to paste it here.

| search query | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 100025143 | `MAX(INDEX((A2=Sheet1!A$1:A$7335)*Sheet1!B$1:B$7335,))` |
| 100138224 | `MAX(INDEX((A3=Sheet1!A$1:A$7335)*Sheet1!B$1:B$7335,))` |
| 100280645 | `MAX(INDEX((A4=Sheet1!A$1:A$7335)*Sheet1!B$1:B$7335,))` |
| 100301369 | `MAX(INDEX((A5=Sheet1!A$1:A$7335)*Sheet1!B$1:B$7335,))` |
| 100336288 | `MAX(INDEX((A6=Sheet1!A$1:A$7335)*Sheet1!B$1:B$7335,))` |
| 100283819 | `MAX(INDEX((A7=Sheet1!A$1:A$7335)*Sheet1!B$1:B$7335,))` |
| 100281696 | `MAX(INDEX((A8=Sheet1!A$1:A$7335)*Sheet1!B$1:B$7335,))` |
| 100149591 | `MAX(INDEX((A9=Sheet1!A$1:A$7335)*Sheet1!B$1:B$7335,))` |
| 100099054 | `MAX(INDEX((A10=Sheet1!A$1:A$7335)*Sheet1!B$1:B$7335,))` |

Comment: Something like `=XLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$7335,Sheet1!$B$2:$C$7335)`? Looks up the _search query_ column and returns the _date_ and _cost_ columns.

Answer (score 0):

[VLOOKUP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) does exactly this - it looks for a value in the first column of a matrix, and when found one, it returns the value of a cell in a later column in the same line. The syntax goes:

*VLOOKUP(lookup_value, table_array, col_index_num, [range_lookup])*

where

- *lookup_value* is the value to look for (the search query in your example)
- *table_array* is the table/matrix containing all your data (or at least the relevant parts).
- *col_index_num* is the number of the target column w.r.t. this matrix
- *range_lookup* is False if you want to look for exact matches of your lookup_value and True if you want to look for approximate values of it.

Keep in mind that

1. the *lookup_value* has to be in the first column of the *table_array*, and
2. the table is searched from top to bottom and stops after the first fit, meaning that if you have duplicates of *lookup_value* in your table, VLOOKUP will only find the first one.

p.s.: In the newer excel versions you also have [XLOOKUP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/xlookup-function-b7fd680e-6d10-43e6-84f9-88eae8bf5929) as an improvement/ enhancement over VLOOKUP.

Comment: the only issue is that there might be multiple of the same date. so it might pull up a random amount not corresponding to what i want

Comment: you're referring to duplicates of the search query, like 100336288 appearing multiple times in the table, right? In that case we need to know what the expected results should look like, cause there is no way of knowing which of the amounts for a search_query is the right one. What would you expect for e.g. 100336288 ?

Comment: I am trying to find the cell directly to the right of the most recent date. Say for instance 100336288 appears 10 times and it has 10 different dates. i want the cell 1 to the right of the most recent date. so it if input 100336288 it pulls up £200 instead of £3,000

Comment: Your table seems to be sorted by date, is that right? In that case VLOOKUP is fine, cause it always uses the topmost line that it finds for a search query - which, in a table sorted by date, will be the most recent entry.

Comment: ah perfect i was unsure if i used vlookup that it would pull the wrong results. thank you for your help.